# Uncaught TypeError: start.getDate is not a function

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am working on an appointment system with full calendar. I want when an array of dates are selected, the values of those dates will be echoed on a div for the user to see his selected dates and can also unselect the dates.

I have been trying to console.log selected dates but I get the above error. It is becoming impossible for me to move ahead.

```js
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      start: 'title',
      center: '',
      end: ''

    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    selectable: true,
    select: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
      date: date.getDate();
      backgroundColor: 'green';

      console.log('Selected:  ' + date);
    },
  )
};
```

I have added `date.toString()` but it is not working. I have tried to use start and end of date but still not working as expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) I see that the select function should accept one parameter. For example:

```
select: function(selectionInfo){ 
... // then here you can have: selectionInfo.start 
 }
```